# How can you Json serialize an object?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button29_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button29.Click

    Dim T = New With {Key .auth = "amVyb2VuLmJha2tlckBjb25uZWN0cmljay5ubDpxa2FXUjNaRkx1ZjdxRDAyVXVvd25iOVQ5YWFxaEU9aHpreWxvOjQ2OGZlMTkxNjk2MGFiZmZkNDVlY2VhYTQ5MzA1NzVi"}
    JsonHelper.JsonSerializer(T)

End Sub

Public Class JsonHelper
    Public Shared Function JsonSerializer(Of T)(ByVal obj As T) As String
        Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        ser.WriteObject(ms, obj)
        Dim jsonString As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        ms.Close()

        Return jsonString

    End Function
End Class
```

At `ser.WriteObject(ms, obj)`, I get the error:

> The type VB $ AnonymousType_0`1 [System.String] can not be serialized. To work around this problem, type the type with the DataContractAttribute attribute and mark all members that you want to serialize with DataMemberAttribute. If the type is a collection, you can bypass this problem by marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET documentation for other supported types.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need a concrete type (class) - the error message tells you that. You would not be able to tell what the T is in that method and JSON.NET cant figure it out either.

Comment: This is an anonymus type. I also tried making a Can you explain how to make a proper class by an example?

Comment: When I add T as a class I get the error 'The type WindowsApplication1.T can not be serialized'.